# docx4j / xlsx4j : create simple spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, docx, xlsx, docx4j

I want to create a simple spreadsheet in docx4j / xlsx4j. It shall contain only Strings, no formular is needed. The porpuse is basically switching from a CSV to XLSX
Therefore I tried the example here: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/xlsx4j/org/xlsx4j/samples/CreateSimpleSpreadsheet.java
Unfortunetly it is not working. Even after removing the deprecated parts ( http://pastebin.com/bUnJWmFD ).

Excel reports unreadable content and suggest a repair. After that I get the error: "Entfernte Datensätze: Zellinformationen von /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-Part". It means something like "removed datasets: Cellinformation at /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-Part".

This error occures when `createCell` is called in line 58 (see. Github, not pastebin) or `cell.setV` is called with `"Hello World"` instead of `"1234"`

Comment: URL for sample was changed, now it is:
https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-xlsx4j/src/main/java/org/xlsx4j/samples/CreateSimpleSpreadsheet.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are raising 2 issues here:

1. the resulting XLSX needing repair:  this was the result of a typo in cell2.setR, fixed at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/7d04a65057ad61f5197fb9a98168fc654220f61f
2. calling setV with "Hello World", you shouldn't do that.  Per http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/SpreadsheetML/v.html

> This element expresses the value contained in a cell. If the cell
>   contains a string, then this value is an index into the shared string
>   table, pointing to the actual string value. Otherwise, the value of
>   the cell is expressed directly in this element. .. For applications
>   not wanting to implement the shared string table, an 'inline string'
>   may be expressed in an <is> element under <c> (instead of a
>   <v> element under <c>),in the same way a string would be
>   expressed in the shared string table.

though I guess our setV method could detect misuse and either throw an exception or do one of those other things instead.

The CreateSimpleSpreadsheet sample as it stands shows you how to set an inline string, so you just need to test whether your input is a number or not.

Comment: thanks for your reply, your commit works for me!
I like you to know, that I did not receive any activation email (tried different email addresses) in your board at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/ . Therefore I came to stackoverflow with this issue.

Comment: Yeah, we had upgraded the server but hadn't installed sendmail until yesterday!  Thanks.